# PHP recordset to array: array with all IDs returned by a query

Tags: php, arrays, recordset

I have this query:

```
"SELECT gs.id FROM table1 gs WHERE gs.external_id = " . $external_id . " ";
```

I would like have a PHP array with all returned IDs like this:

```
$arr_ids = array(1,2,34,14);
```

I know i can do this using while, but i would like to know if there is a function
or a more elegant way for doing this:

```
$result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $result[] = $row['id'];
}
unset($rs);
unset($row);
```

Thanks

Comment: more elegant way? that seems okay to me

Comment: Not really, that's about it right there.

Comment: Still using mysql_* extension?

Comment: you can try with `array_values()` but it will also return indexed array with numbers.

Comment: yeah, the only thing to change is change to `mysqli_` or `PDO` and use prepared statements

Comment: @sectus and Ghost thank you for your tip! I will look to use mysqli or PDO for next projects.

Comment: @lethal.industry , this part of code will be changed in your next projects.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation).

Answer (score 0):

There is a more elegant way. You should by using `mysqli` functions (instead of `mysql`). [See this question and answer for more information about this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

You can use [`mysqli_result::fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) without using a loop. Following an example how to use it.

```
// Connect to database
$sqlConn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

// Build SQL String
$sqlString = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

// Execute the query and put data into a result
$result = $this->sqlConn->query($sqlString);

// Copy result into a associative array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Copy result into a numeric array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);

// Copy result into both a associative and numeric array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Comment: `When using mysqli, you can use PDOStatement::fetchAll() without using a loop.` Please consider proofreading that statement

Comment: after all these suggestions, sure i will take a look at that question and answer and i will move to this method. thanks

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Thanks for your advice. I'm regularly using both synonymously, as - iirc - `mysqli` is the MySQL implementation of PDO.